# Large Image in .net

Tags: c#, image, bitmap

I want to create large image by C#. (i have some photos with large size (4800 * 4800). i want to merge these photos.)

I use Bitmap but don't support. (Error : Invalid Parameter)

Comment: Could you provide some code please?

Answer (score 1):

Some code would be useful ...

... However, to hazard an educated guess, I suspect you're trying to create an instance of `Bitmap` with either Width or Height (or both) greater than 2^15.

Essentially, you can't - the .NET bitmap classes have a limitation on how big an image they can handle. Your original 4800 pixel square images won't be a problem, but going over 32,767 pixels will be.

Comment: But it *will* be a problem even with "smaller" bitmaps. A 4800^2 bitmap requires 88Mb of *contigous* memory. Juggling around several of those simultaneously may cause an out of memory exception.

Comment: That's true - I've written a couple of image processing toys that ran out of memory because of naive assumptions on my part. They didn't fail with an "Invalid Parameter" error though, so I didn't think it relevant to the original question. You make a good point though - trying to load and process too many 4800x4800 images will blow out memory consumption, especially if very many copies are kept around.

Answer (score 0):

you might like to check [AForge.NET](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/), it has a large image processor built in, and it's open source.

Comment: Thanks. but my country (Iran) can't Access to "code.google.com". Google don't Allow us.